How to visualise the value of one predictor in a multiple linear regression
I'm looking for confirmation on whether the approach I have is statistically correct / straightforward, and if there might be any references supporting this line of thinking on how to visualise outputs from a multiple linear regression...
I am running a multiple linear regression where I have a continuous response variable (log10-volume), being predicted by a continuous variable (score). I have included three nuisance covariates in the model (age [continuous], head size [continuous], and group [ordinal]), because I am interested in whether score predicts log10-volume after accounting for the effects of age, head size, and group. The formula (sorry, R notation), looks like this:
log10-volume ~ score + age + head size + group
The approach i've taken is to first save the residuals of a multiple linear regression where log10-volume is predicted by these nuisance covariates (age, head size, and group):
log10-volume ~ age + head size + group
Then, I plot these residuals on the y axis, and score on the x axis (formula below):

residuals(log-10 volume) ~ score
I am showing these plots in a presentation in a few days, and am just wanting confirmation on whether these plots correctly visualise whether score predicts log10-volume after accounting for the effects of these nuisance covariates.
Thank you for reading!

Well, start by looking at your model summary if you are using R: summary(mod)
You should see a column "Estimate" and you can look at the value of the coeficient you're interested in. Is it positive? Is it significantly different than 0?
If you specifically want a visualization, one option is to use the predict() function to generate predictions for your "score" data while holding your other covariates constant, and then plotting those predictions. This could show any effect you're interested in, and should be fine for this model where you don't have any interaction terms.

Hi, thank you for your explanation! I am following up on your suggestion to use the predict() function to visualise the effect of "score" on volume, after accounting for covariate effects. How might you go about holding "group" constant, if it is an ordinal variable with 5 levels? I can imagine I could set age and head size at their mean values...
